# Program applies Method to entire Array in 2D Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want to use a method on an object in a 2D Array, but the program applies it to the entire Array.

I tried:`board[0][1].openField();`

board is initialised like this:

```
Field[][] board =new Field[8][8];
for(Field[] row:board){
            Arrays.fill(row,new Field());
        }
```

The method openField() looks like this:

```
public boolean openField(){
        boolean error;
        if(!open){
            open=true;
            error=false;
        } else{
            error=true;
        }
        return error;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've only instantiated one object. `Arrays.fill()` just copies the same reference to each spot in the array. If you want to populate them with separate instances, you can pass a lambda to `Arrays.setAll()`:

```
Arrays.setAll(row, i -> new Field());
```

Or you can use an ordinary loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    row[i] = new Field();
}
```